# Substring by a "." in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string that consists of "apple.jpg"
I am trying to perform a substring such that it will return me the value before "." which is apple.

Below is my code, but it does not return me with any value:

```
 str="apple.jpg";
 $subString = document.write(str.substring(".");
 echo ($subString);
```

How should I go about doing it?

Comment: What's that language ? a kind of PHP ?

Comment: You are missing a `)`

Comment: @Doorknob , I was just gonna say it. I hope yours was sarcastic too.

Answer (score 3):

You can try splitting the string and getting the first element of the array:

```
myArray = str.split(".");
name = myArray[0];
```

The above is *pseudocode* as I'm not sure which language you're using... (You've combined JavaScript and PHP in your example!)

Note that is `str` is something like `some.word.jpg`, the above code will return only `some`.

If this is a problem, try using `lastIndexOf()`, like so:

```
name = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Note that the above is now JavaScript as there is no `lastIndexOf` function in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

you can use str.indexOf("."); and then use the substring function

maybe like this `str.substring(0,str.indexOf("."));`

Answer (score 0):

even you are mixing php and js. try looking for a function called lastIndexOf().

that find the las position of a given string

Answer (score 0):

`substring()` wants the startposition and the length of the substring you want it to return (see [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)). You would need to add `indexOf()` to get the desired result:

```
$subString = document.write(str.substring(0,indexOf(str, ".")));
```

Comment: I took the liberty of changing your w3scools link to a Mozilla Dev one, for [this](http://w3fools.com) reason.

Comment: Also, should you be really using `document.write()`?

Comment: @MMM thanks for that, and thanks for the "this" link! That's a great initiative!

Answer (score 0):

Part from the mixed info there is a way in javascript and php

javascript:

```
str="apple.jpg";
 $subString = str.split(".");
document.write($substring[0]);
```

php:

```
$str="apple.jpg";
 $subString = explode(".", $str);
echo $substring[0];
```

Although it is better not to use the $ sign in the variables in javascript.

Comment: Using $ in variable names is fine in ES5. There was a restriction in ECMA-262 ed 3 that was largely ignored by some popular libraries, so it's now allowed.

Comment: Some developers who use jQuery use `$` to denote document elements returned by jQuery, e.g. `$myDiv = $("#my-div")`

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag, so it's users shouldn't be confused that $varname is a jQuery object. In this case at least. ;-)

Comment: @MMM - Still, due to restrictions (in the past) I would advice not to. Especially if you are not a seasoned programmer yet. :)